# JavaFX WebView don't manage touch scroll if inserted in JFXPanel

Tags: java, javafx-8, javafx-2, javafx-webengine

I have attached a JFXPanel to a JFrame and tried to show oracle site. Dimension of Jframe are limited so a scroll bar is shown, than to scroll the site i need to use the scroll bar or the mouse wheel, it seams that mouse dragged or tuoch scroll is not manage.
below the source code of my application (copied from javafx oracle tutorial site)

```
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEvent;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import static javafx.concurrent.Worker.State.FAILED;

public class SimpleSwingBrowser extends JFrame {

    private final JFXPanel jfxPanel = new JFXPanel();
    private WebEngine engine;

    private final JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    private final JLabel lblStatus = new JLabel();


    private final JButton btnGo = new JButton("Go");
    private final JTextField txtURL = new JTextField();
    private final JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar();

    public SimpleSwingBrowser() {
        super();
        initComponents();
    }


    private void initComponents() {
        createScene();

        ActionListener al = new ActionListener() {
            @Override 
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                loadURL(txtURL.getText());
            }
        };

        btnGo.addActionListener(al);
        txtURL.addActionListener(al);

        progressBar.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 18));
        progressBar.setStringPainted(true);

        JPanel topBar = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(5, 0));
        topBar.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(3, 5, 3, 5));
        topBar.add(txtURL, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        topBar.add(btnGo, BorderLayout.EAST);

        JPanel statusBar = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(5, 0));
        statusBar.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(3, 5, 3, 5));
        statusBar.add(lblStatus, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        statusBar.add(progressBar, BorderLayout.EAST);

        panel.add(topBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panel.add(jfxPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.add(statusBar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        getContentPane().add(panel);

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1024, 600));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();

    }

    private void createScene() {

        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override 
            public void run() {

                WebView view = new WebView();
                engine = view.getEngine();

                engine.titleProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, final String newValue) {
                        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                            @Override 
                            public void run() {
                                SimpleSwingBrowser.this.setTitle(newValue);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });

                engine.setOnStatusChanged(new EventHandler<WebEvent<String>>() {
                    @Override 
                    public void handle(final WebEvent<String> event) {
                        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                            @Override 
                            public void run() {
                                lblStatus.setText(event.getData());
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });

                engine.locationProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> ov, String oldValue, final String newValue) {
                        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                            @Override 
                            public void run() {
                                txtURL.setText(newValue);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });

                engine.getLoadWorker().workDoneProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
                    @Override
                    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observableValue, Number oldValue, final Number newValue) {
                        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                            @Override 
                            public void run() {
                                progressBar.setValue(newValue.intValue());
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });

                engine.getLoadWorker()
                        .exceptionProperty()
                        .addListener(new ChangeListener<Throwable>() {

                            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Throwable> o, Throwable old, final Throwable value) {
                                if (engine.getLoadWorker().getState() == FAILED) {
                                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                                        @Override public void run() {
                                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                                                    panel,
                                                    (value != null) ?
                                                    engine.getLocation() + "\n" + value.getMessage() :
                                                    engine.getLocation() + "\nUnexpected error.",
                                                    "Loading error...",
                                                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        });

                jfxPanel.setScene(new Scene(view));
            }
        });
    }

    public void loadURL(final String url) {
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override 
            public void run() {
                String tmp = toURL(url);

                if (tmp == null) {
                    tmp = toURL("http://" + url);
                }

                engine.load(tmp);
            }
        });
    }

    private static String toURL(String str) {
        try {
            return new URL(str).toExternalForm();
        } catch (MalformedURLException exception) {
                return null;
        }
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                SimpleSwingBrowser browser = new SimpleSwingBrowser();
                browser.setVisible(true);
                browser.loadURL("http://oracle.com");
           }     
       });
    }
}
```

If, instead, i put the webviev to an application without using a JFXPanel touch scroll and mouse dragged work perfectly. below the code coming from javafx orcle tutorial too:

```
import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.VPos;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class WebViewSample extends Application {
    private Scene scene;
    @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
        // create the scene
        stage.setTitle("Web View");  
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
          @Override 
          public void run() {
        scene = new Scene(new Browser(),900,600, Color.web("#666970"));
        stage.setScene(scene);
          }});
//        scene.getStylesheets().add("webviewsample/BrowserToolbar.css");        
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }
}
class Browser extends Region {

    final WebView browser = new WebView();
    final WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();

    public Browser() {

        //apply the styles
        getStyleClass().add("browser");
        // load the web page
        webEngine.load("http://www.oracle.com/products/index.html");
        //add the web view to the scene
        getChildren().add(browser);

    }
    private Node createSpacer() {
        Region spacer = new Region();
        HBox.setHgrow(spacer, Priority.ALWAYS);
        return spacer;
    }

    @Override protected void layoutChildren() {
        double w = getWidth();
        double h = getHeight();
        layoutInArea(browser,0,0,w,h,0, HPos.CENTER, VPos.CENTER);
    }

    @Override protected double computePrefWidth(double height) {
        return 900;
    }

    @Override protected double computePrefHeight(double width) {
        return 600;
    }
}
```

Can someone tell my if i'm missing something ?

Comment: It is a JavaFX bug, i segnaled it to oracle and it should be fixed in openjfx 12. Below the link to the bug :
https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8213733

Answer (score 1):

for everybody who has the same problem, this is a JavaFx issue I reported it to oracle and it should be fixed in openjdk12.
Below the link to the bug :
https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8213733